# Update static content in dockerized replicated architecture

Tags: docker, architecture, microservices, kong, swarm

I’m building a dockerized backend microservice architecture with swarm, where I have a gateway instance (more specifically a Kong Gateway instance, very similar to NGINX) sitting at the front of the public interface.

This gateway acts as a proxy to the different services located in my private VPC, as well as distributing the static content. It is replicated to a minimum of 3 instances, for high availability, randomly through the available servers in the cluster.

CI/CD is set up to update the services with their new image versions in every successful git merge to the master branch (after testing, building and tagging). This includes the static assets, which is a repo of its own (this repo in particular is not a dockerized project, just the files).

I’m trying to figure out which could be the best approach for updating the static assets across all the gateway instances when a new version is available:

- make the gateway docker image a custom image containing the Kong service + the static assets. This allows to have inmutable container philosophy, at the cost of mixing responsibilities in the same image: static asset update and gateway update. Also, rolling update of the service on each new version of the static content means that at least one instance will be down on every static file update. This approach also requires to tag the container image with both the gateway version and the static version to uniquely identify all dependency versions.
- Make the static content be served by another microservice. I could create a new service only for serving the static assets, and make the gateway redirect to that service on every static asset request. This approach adds an extra step in the flow for just serving static content, increasing latency and also increases maintenance costs (create a new service also means keeping that code up to date, even if it is the simplest code of all). Also, given the fact that Kong is capable of serving static assets, it’s a waste of resources making a new service just for that. The pros of this is that it separates responsibilities.

Is there any other approach that I could use for this case?

It is a shame that docker swarm configs feature is restricted to one file and limited in size. It could be great if I could update my static assets to the gateway service by updating its configs.

Thanks

Comment: I would go with 2nd approach + dockerize the static assets(simply pack it in nignx:alpine), it's more cleaner and makes backend services unified.

Comment: I've finally decoupled all the static assets to an AWS S3 bucket+cloudwatch, thus separating backend API with static assets. I think this may be the cleanest solution